# R xlsx Excel number formats

Tags: r, number-formatting, xlsx

I have created a workbook (createWorkbook) and formatted the headings, however how do I format the number values such that when I write/save to Excel I get the following:

For the first field e.g.
3615 becomes 3,615

For subsequent fields e.g.
70.658 becomes 70.7

Note, I still want Excel to recognize the values as doubles.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean by field the next column or the next row. And you should be using the package openxlsx for this.

Comment: Thanks phiver, just discovered openxslsx, much better... question on openxlsx though; for addStyle(wb, 1, style = s, rows = 5:100, cols = 1:2, gridExpand = TRUE) how do I set the style for the whole column. It looks like I have to explicitly state the number of rows

Comment: You need to specify the rows. You could always specify 1 million. I'm not sure if that wouldn't bloat excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be considered. This approach can be used only on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_Excel_File <- "D:/Dropbox/Reponses_Stackoverflow/stackoverflow_346/empty_Excel_File.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlApp[["UseSystemSeparators"]] <- FALSE 
xlApp[["DecimalSeparator"]] <- "."
xlApp[["ThousandsSeparator"]] <- ","
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()

vector_Val <- c(3615, 70.658)
vector_Format <- c("#,##0", "0.0")
nb_Val <- length(vector_Val)

for(i in 1 : nb_Val)
{
  cell_Obj <- Sheets[[1]]$Cells(1, i)
  cell_Obj[["Value"]] <- vector_Val[i]
  cell_Obj[["NumberFormat"]] <- vector_Format[i]
}
```